# How to make a column as a layer of label?

Tags: labeling, mapinfo

I have a table with many columns, some of them are "lon/lat" and "Name". After I draw objects on a map.

- How can I make a layer by the content of the column "Name"?
- How can I make a legend automatically? for example:

  red ---2G

  Blue---3G

  Green--2G&3G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a thematic map based on your layer and the column holding these values (2G, 3G, 2G/3G, etc).

If your table isn't mappable you need to create points from your long/lat columns - use the function Create Points to do this. Then add your table to a map window or show it in a new map window.

Make sure you create an Individual theme and select a point based template.

After you have selected the type of theme and input table and input column, you can assign specific styles for each of your values. This is where you specify what colour each of your values should have.

Comment: Peter, imagine that I have a table with 3 column: Lon, Lat, Name. I can make a map by drawing all points based on Lon, Lat. At that time, I have a map with one layer (all the points), please help me how to make one more layer with the text above every point by the content of the column "Name" of that table

Comment: You can turn on Autolabels for your layer and specify to use the Name column for yur labelling. You specify this via the Layer Properties dialog - double click on the layer in the Layer Control to get to this dialog.

Comment: Peter, Is there other way to do that automatically by the command in a fuction?

Comment: Such as: Set Map Layer MYLAYER Label Auto On With NAME

Comment: OK Peter, if I would like to use that layer as a table in order to load that layer (table) in other maps, how can I do that?

Comment: Isn't that what I answered above? You can add your table to as many maps as you want. Once you have added your table to a map, it's seen as a layer in the map

Comment: Sorry Peter, because I'm so new to Mapbasic, so the same problem but I ask many things. I do as what you tell but that time the symbol (lon/lat) and the lable belong to the same layer. If I hide the symbol, the label will hide too, I would like they belong to 2 difference layers, can you help me?

Comment: You can set the layer to display an invisible symbol. In that way you can only see the label and not the point. If you open the MapBasic window (via Options) and then do it via the Layer Control you'll see the MapBasic statement to use in the MapBasic Window